# EqualityComparer recursive calls (as used in operator== implementation generated by Visual Studio quick action)

Tags: c#

Given following original class:

```
        public class Sample
        {
            public string One;
            public string Two;
        }
```

in Visual Studio (16.9.4) you can run "Generate Equals" Quick Action and then select "Implement IEquatable" and "Generate operators". It will generate following code:

```
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return Equals(obj as Sample);
            }

            public bool Equals(Sample other)
            {
                return other != null &&
                       One == other.One &&
                       Two == other.Two;
            }

            public static bool operator ==(Sample left, Sample right)
            {
                return EqualityComparer<Sample>.Default.Equals(left, right);
            }

            public static bool operator !=(Sample left, Sample right)
            {
                return !(left == right);
            }
```

This is recursive - `operator==` will call `EqualityComparer` that could call `operator==` again which will call `EqualityComparer` again:

[image: example of recursive calls]

In this case, when both `left` and `right` are not null the `EqualityComparer` calls `Sample.Equals`, but when one of them is null, it does not, breaking the infinite loop.

But is there a guarantee it will work like that - that there won't be infinite loop? I mean, it makes sense, but it'd be nice if, for example, documentation also supported it... I've checked `EqualityComparer` docs and could not find anything...

Comment: I can't find any such docs either. I would rather stay on the safe side and use `!ReferenceEquals(other, null)` instead.

Comment: Please report this to Microsoft via the in-built Visual Studio issue reporting functionality. You can add a link to this question so they have context.

Comment: @Sweeper Personally I find `!(other is null)` more concise

Comment: @IanKemp what would be the reason for reporting this? Do you think the code is wrong?

Comment: You've demonstrated a scenario that results in generating code that leads to apparent infinite recursion. Visual Studio should not be generating code that does that, because it will lead to unhappy developers. So if you report the issue to MS they can look into it and either agree with you and push through a fix, or explain to you why you're incorrect.

Comment: @IanKemp as I wrote in the post, it's NOT infinite recursion - `EqualityComparer` does not do recursive call in case one of arguments is null

Comment: @pkruk Comparing two non-null instances is pretty common, don't you think? For that reason alone it should be reported to MS.

Comment: @StevenRands EqualityComparer doc says: 

_The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable<T> generic interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer<T> that invokes the implementation of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer<T>, as provided by T_

I don't understand the 2nd sentence, but the first says it'll call Equals(). So it's not wrong that Sample.Equals() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating `!= null` was a bug in Visual Studio (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39253) that is fixed in an upcoming preview.

Luckily there was a guarantee that there would not be recursion. `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` never calls `IEquatable<T>.Equals` with a null parameter: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/EqualityComparer.cs,8cac2a4adf6f0740.